# Oracle SQL: Copy and update records within a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 30 records for 'Orders'. I'm trying to

1. copy these records,
2. change several fields to make these records 'Sales' records, and
3. append the updated records to the table.

There is an ID field that's sequential. I'm trying to use the following code which is not working:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_01 (
    ID, 
    CONTROL_CODE, 
    CODE, 
    RULE_CODE, 
    CAT, 
    INPUT_VALUES,
    UPDATER,
    UPDATE_TIMESTAMP) 
    SELECT 
        (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE_01) + 1,
        CONTROL_CODE, 
        CODE, 
        'SALES',
        CAT, 
        INPUT_VALUES,
        'ME',
        SYSDATE
    FROM
        TABLE_01
    WHERE
        ID IN (
            SELECT
                ID
            FROM
                TABLE_01
            WHERE
                RULE_CODE = 'ORDERS');
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You say it's sequential, but is the `ID` column a sequence? If so, you don't need to explicitly insert it

Comment: The ID column is not a sequence

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: The error is a unique constraint error on the PK 'ID'. I think what's happening is that the the select statement is picking up multiple rows, as it should. But the ..max (id) statement is trying to insert the duplicate IDs

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this code

```
(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE_01) + 1,
```

Returns the same value for every row. It doesn't do one insert, run the query again, do the second insert, etc. Instead it runs the query once, and then batch inserts all of the rows that come back. If you run the select statement by itself, without the insert, you'll see what I mean. Try this instead:

```
(SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLE_01) + rownum,
```